# Finding out if a path is straight line of has some jagged curves from series of latitude longitude data

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, geodjango

I have a list of[ {'latitude' : latitude, 'longitude' : longitude}] data and I am looking for a python based library that I can use to analyse this and tell me the percentage of path that is a pure straight line

Example of such a path is here : http://gyazo.com/e65a4ecf43161bdfd126316f39c4d403

Thanks in advance

#### Update

I have attached a picture of the route on the map I am looking at. basically , it is the path of running of a person that is around 4 kms long. As seen on the map, the path of this "run" is very much a straight line, and that over 4 kms is impossible in the center of a city (which is where this run has occured), leading to the conclusion that this was done using a transport (underground metro).
The algorithm I want to find is to detect such a finding, that is clearly evident to the naked eye - programmatically

[image]

Comment: Most roads generally travel in one direction. Are you looking for the longest path on one road? Or the general 'straight-ness' of the road, compared to how the crow flies?

Comment: Please clarify this question. Are you looking for the longest straight segment within the path? How much of path is straight starting at the beginning? The sum of the length of various straight segments within the whole path? What do you mean by "straight"? Do you mean conforming to a great circle route? How much deviation from "straight" will you tolerate before you declare the path crooked?

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments, I have updated the original post with more explanation of what I am trying to achieve and a picture (starting with section header "Update")

Comment: Any suggestions on this?